# How to change english coupon text field into polish text

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with some fields in english. I have a polish version of CiviCRM,
but the field "If you have a discount code, enter it here" is in english.

Here is our website:
https://crm.mieszkanicznik.org.pl/oplacenie-czlonkostwa/

Where can I find this field and where can I change this text into polish?

Could you send me some tips how can I do it?

I'll be waiting for your reply.

Best regards,
Mietek

Answer (score 0):

It's coming from the cividiscount extension. Maybe you didn't download the translations for the extension? The easiest way is with https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update. See also https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/wikis/extension-translation#installing-translation-mo-files-for-an-extension

If there is no Polish translation for that extension, then you can do a quick manual replacement at Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Word Replacements.